# Javascript drag div inside viewport container

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, draggable, viewport

I am trying to achieve a drag and drop feature for mobile devices... there is a container div with a fixed width/height and inside it another div with contents but it's size is way bigger than the parent.

My issue is that once I click on the draggable div I am able to move it around but I don't really find any solution to keep the draggable element position the same every time I start touchmove on the screen..

I try to keep this as minimal as possible
Also I dont want to use jQueryUI

P.S. Dragging the element will only work on desktop by using touch emulation

Here is an example
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgso4dve/5/)

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="draggable">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('touchmove','.draggable',function(e){

        //Prevent default for mobile devices so the element inside the container can be dragged witouth stopping
        //e.preventDefault();

        //Calculating the distance where the touch event stopped
        var xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        var yPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;


        //Moving the draggable element around
        $(this).css({
            left: xPos + $(this).offset().left + 'px',
            top: yPos + $(this).offset().top + 'px'
        });

    });
</script>

<style>
    .container
    {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
    .draggable
    {
        width:1000px;
        height:1000px;
        background:url('http://th04.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/f/2014/249/d/f/seraphim_by_alexiuss-d7y4v0o.jpg');
        position:relative;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is empty.

Comment: You need the container div to 'mask' the draggable element? I got this right? What I know didn't get is: what is the draggable element supposed to do? You can drag it around. And then? Where it should be dropped (since its drag & drop) JSfiddle doesn't emulate mobile events, so I can't really test it.

Comment: That's the problem I encountered...I do not want to drag the element inside container from top left of it, I want to drag it from the position I touched the element .So basicly the element inside it should work same as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WBv9r/1/light/

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the change in position not, the current position. So what this means is you'll need to get the `pageX` and `pageY` on `touchstart` save those in some variable you can access later, perhaps like this:

```
var touch_x= 0;
var touch_y= 0;
```

On `touchstart` you can set `touch_x` and `touch_y` to the current `pageX` and `pageY`.

Then on `touchmove` you can reference that and find the difference. So you dont move by `pageX` you move by `touch_x - pageX`. This will cause you to move in both positive and negative directions. Your current code will always have positive number and thus, only move in positive directions.

Comment: finally seems to work as expected, thanks alot for your help.. I got confused by solving this one since I never did anything like this :)

Comment: wait till you try adding in pinch and zoom ;)